# I can't fix this bug on my backend Express

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I have this end point that creates a new server in my database, when I say server, it's just a server name. We have several gaming servers, so, we want to manage them from a website,

```js
const createServer = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { gameName, serverName } = req.body;
  const serverExist = await Server.findOne({ serverName });

  if (!gameName || !serverName) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Please add game name / server name");
  }
  if (!serverExist?.isHidden) {
    // if i set it to just serverExists it works
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("Server exist");
  }
  //Get user using the id in the JWT
  const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
  if (!user) {
    res.status(401);
    throw new Error("User not found");
  }
  const server = {
    gameName,
    serverName,
    user: req.user.id,
  };
  await Server.create(server);
  res.status(201).json(server);
});
```

Now, I'm checking if the server already exists in the database with `serverExist`, it returns all the document about that server, all works good. It has a property called `isHidden`, the time I set it in the `if` statement, the server is not able to return any response. if I set `if` statement to only `if(serverExist)`, it does work, but I need it to work if the server was set to hidden so that a user could re-create it. I don't want to delete as it will be needed for later.

I checked all the returns and all seems ok, even the server object at the end does have the information. The problem is happening when I'm calling the create method. Don't know why adding `serverExist.isHidden` makes it unable to create the document!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a little logic problem.

Consider these states when evaluating `!serverExist?.isHidden`...

| State | `!serverExist?.isHidden` |
| --- | --- |
| No record exists | `true` ⚠️ |
| Record exists with `isHidden: true` | `false` |
| Record exists with `isHidden: false` | `true` |

I would instead include the `isHidden` parameter in your query and use the [Server.exists()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-exists) method

```js
const serverExists = await Server.exists({ serverName, isHidden: true });

if (serverExists) {
  // Server exists and is not hidden
  res.status(409); // 409 Conflict is a better status than 401 Unauthorized
  throw new Error("Server exists");
}
```